# SXA seach Scope is not returning result in Search result component

Tags: sxa, sxa-search

I just added conditions in the search scope.

I could see the result in the backend, but the same is not returning the search result component.

[image]

[image]

If I remove the date condition, it is returning the result.

**Note:**

Event_end_date_s field is the computed field, i just created for filtering.

Comment: Please find the detailed answer here, https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/31244/sxa-custom-search-token-query-wrong-date-format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated the detailed answer here, please find it here

[Sxa custom search token query Wrong date format](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/31244/sxa-custom-search-token-query-wrong-date-format)

Answer (score 1):

Arul,

The field name will be `Event_end_date` or one you have given in your computed index. Don't take the name from **Solr**. As **Solr** indexes are `adding _*` after the field name depending on the field type.

Check where is the computed index added. It should be added in Master DB as well. If you have added in `DefaultSolrConfiguration` then it is available everywhere.

Then check the search log file, find the query you are running and run that query directly in **Solr**.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed info,it helped me to check the solr query