# Sxa custom search token query Wrong date format

Tags: sxa, content-search, sxa-search

I have added a new sxa token processor to filter the passed date events,

**This is my Code**

```
 protected virtual SearchStringModel BuildModel(string fieldName)
    {
        Log.Info($"SXA_Token customSearchModel: {new SearchStringModel("custom", FormattableString.Invariant(FormattableStringFactory.Create("{0}|{1}", (object)fieldName.ToLowerInvariant(), $"[{DateTime.Today.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'fff'Z'")} TO *]")))}", "SXA_Token");
        return new SearchStringModel("custom", FormattableString.Invariant(FormattableStringFactory.Create("{0}|{1}", (object)fieldName.ToLowerInvariant(), (object)$"[{DateTime.Today.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'fff'Z'")} TO *]")))
        {
            Operation = "must"
        };
    }
```

**This is my Solr Query**

```
INFO  Solr Query - ?q=((event_end_date_s:(\[2022\-03\-10T18\:30\:00.000Z\ TO\ *\])
```

**Expected solr Query format**

```
event_end_date_s:[2022-03-10T18:30:00.000Z TO *]
```

How should I format my date and need to remove `\`? I just tried to remove `'` from my code, still no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue. I would like to add my answer here

**My computed field config**

```
 <field fieldName="event_start_date" sourceField="StartDate" returnType="string">Foundation.Search.ComputedFields.DateFieldComputedField, Foundation.Search</field>
              <field fieldName="event_end_date" sourceField="EndDate" returnType="string">Foundation.Search.ComputedFields.DateFieldComputedField, Foundation.Search</field>
```

**Computed field logic**

```
 public object ComputeFieldValue(IIndexable indexable)
    {
        var indexableItem = indexable as SitecoreIndexableItem;
        if (indexableItem == null) return null;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SourceField)) return null;
        var field = indexableItem.Item.Fields[SourceField];
        if (field == null) return null;
        return Getvalue(field);
    }

    private DateTime Getvalue(Field fieldValue)
    {
        DateTime serverTime = DateUtil.IsoDateToDateTime(fieldValue.Value, DateTime.MinValue);
        return DateUtil.ToUniversalTime(serverTime);
    }
```

**SXA Token logic**

```
  public class ExcludePastEvents : ResolveSearchQueryTokensProcessor
{
    protected string TokenPart { get; } = "ExcludeItemWithPreviousDateInDateField";
    private readonly string DateCompareIdentifier = "#datecompare#";

    [SxaTokenKey]
    protected override string TokenKey => FormattableString.Invariant(FormattableStringFactory.Create("{0}|FieldName", (object)this.TokenPart));

    public override void Process(ResolveSearchQueryTokensEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.ContextItem == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        for (int index = 0; index < args.Models.Count; index++)
        {
            SearchStringModel model = args.Models[index];
            if (model.Type.Equals("sxa") && ContainsToken(model))
            {
                string fieldName = model.Value.Replace(TokenPart, string.Empty).TrimStart('|');
                args.Models.Insert(index, this.BuildModel(fieldName));
                args.Models.Remove(model);
            }
        }
    }
    protected virtual SearchStringModel BuildModel(string fieldName)
    {
        try
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(fieldName, "fieldName");

            string fieldFormat = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'fff'Z'";
            DateTime dateTime = DateUtil.ToUniversalTime(DateTime.UtcNow);

            string formatedDate = string.Format(arg1: "*", format: "{2}[{0} TO {1}]", arg0: dateTime.ToString(fieldFormat), arg2: DateCompareIdentifier);

            return new SearchStringModel("custom", FormattableString.Invariant(FormattableStringFactory.Create("{0}|{1}", (object)fieldName.ToLowerInvariant(), formatedDate)))
            {
                Operation = "must"
            };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Info(string.Format("BuildModel - error-{0}stacktrace{1}", ex.Message.ToString(), ex.StackTrace.ToString()), ex);
        }
        return new SearchStringModel();

    }

    protected override bool ContainsToken(SearchStringModel m)
    {
        return Regex.Match(m.Value, FormattableString.Invariant($"{TokenPart}\\|[a-zA-Z ]*")).Success;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to skip the date formatting. It should work.
And if you have the computed field, set the field type DateTime.

```
<field fieldName="date" returnType="datetime">
Maulik.App.ContentSearch.ComputedIndexFields.DateForBoosting,Maulik.App.ContentSearch
</field>
```